# who grows faster? nlgn or lgn! ? and how to get T(n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I got a algorithm
n is array's length.
and binary_search(array, 0, n, value) 's T(n) is T(n) = Theta(lgn).

```
CHECK_VALUE_IN_ARRAY(array, n, value)
for i = 1 to n
    binary_search(array, i, n, value)
```

how to get T(n) ?
Here is my steps:

```
T(n) = c(lg(1) + lg(2) + lg(3) + ...+ lg(n)) 
    = clgn!
    = Theta(lgn!)
```

Is this right?

2) If this is right?
   Who grows faster?
   nlgn vs lgn!

Thank you very much

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large `n` both are identical, more precisely their ratio converges towards 1.  Even more precisely, you have roughly

```
log(n!) == n*(log(n)-1)
```

If you want to be exact, you will find

```
log(n!) == n*(log(n)-1) + 1/2*log(2*Pi*n) + O(1/n)
```

**EDIT:** A good source for this is wolframalpha.com , ask for `Series(Log(n!))`

Answer (score 2):

Your calculations are correct!

log(n!) = log(1*2*3*......(n-1)*n)

```
     =log(1)+log(2)+log(3)+......log(n)

     <=log(n)+log(n)+log(n)+........log(n)

     =nlog(n)
```

so, log(n!)<=nlog(n)

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotically both are similar because according to stirling's approximation `log(n!) = nlogn - n + O(logn)` on which if you do amortized analysis it will give the same `O(nlogn)` bound

[Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)