# Get the running time T(n)

Tags: performance, time, complexity-theory, time-complexity

A algorithm core is like the following.

```
CHECK_VALUE_IN_ARRAY(array, n, value)
for i = 1 to n
    binary_search(array, i, n, value)
```

And already know binary_search(array,1,n,value)'s T(n) = Theta(lgn)
how to get T(n) ?

PS:
 My steps:

```
 T(n) = t(n) + t(n-1) + ... + t(1)
      = lg(n) + lg(n-1) + ... + lg(1)
      = lgn!
```

Is this right?

Comment: CHECK_VALUE_IN_ARRAY(array, n, value) for i = 1 to n binary_search(array, i, n, value)

Comment: What part of it are you stuck on? Have you tried summing up the runtimes of binary_search for each value of i?

Comment: What does `binary_search` do? Does its runtime depend on `i`?

Comment: I get it by these steps:

Comment: If `binary_search()` is `Theta(lg n)`, then `CHECK_VALUE_IN_ARRAY()` is `Theta(n lg n)`.

Comment: @Jack  how do you get it ?

Comment: Because you perform `binary_search()` n times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [who grows faster? nlgn or lgn! ? and how to get T(n)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698840/who-grows-faster-nlgn-or-lgn-and-how-to-get-tn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `binary_search(array, i, n, value)` searches elements i ... n of the array for `value` using binary search, then yes, your analysis is correct. The runtime will be

> Θ(log 1 + log 2 + log 3 + ... + log n) = Θ(log n!)

Note that by [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), log n! = Θ(n log n), so the total runtime would be Θ(n log n).

Hope this helps!